# Scraping a JS heavy website on Windows - using Scrapy + (Playwright/Selenium/Puppeteer) excluding Splash

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scrapy, puppeteer, playwright-python

I am trying to scrape a JS heavy Website using Scrapy, which means I have to render the page first.

I have trouble following scraped links since Scrapy only does:

```
for link in links:
   respsonse.follow(link, ...)
```

Splash does not work for me.

Here is the link I have to scrape: https://www.wuerth.de/web/de/awkg/kompetenz/din_iso_normteile/iso-7380-din-34805-linsenkopfschrauben.php?CampaignName=SR009

I would like to follow every `a.card-model.card-link::attr(href)` and get information from there.

Here is what I came up with so far:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod

class SpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.wuerth.de"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.wuerth.de/web/de/awkg/kompetenz/din_iso_normteile/iso-7380-din-34805-linsenkopfschrauben.php?CampaignName=SR009"]

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.wuerth.de/web/de/awkg/kompetenz/din_iso_normteile/iso-7380-din-34805-linsenkopfschrauben.php?CampaignName=SR009', meta=dict(
            playwright = True,
            playwright_include_page = True,
            playwright_page_methods =[PageMethod('wait_for_selector', 'a.card-model.card-link::attr(href)')], 
            errback=self.errback,
        ))

    async def parse(self, response):
        
        for link in response.css('a.card-model.card-link::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(link,callback=self.parse_screw,meta=dict(
            playwright = True,
            playwright_include_page = True,
            playwright_page_methods =[PageMethod('wait_for_selector', 'a.card-model.card-link::attr(href)')], 
            errback=self.errback,
        ))

    async def parse_screw(self, response):
        attributes = response.css('div.properties ul li::text').getall()
        for screw in response.css('text-prewrap::text'):
            yield {
                'article' : screw,
            }

    async def errback(self, failure):
        page = failure.request.meta["playwright_page"]
        await page.close()
```

Spider runs without an error but doesn't get any information. It runs on WSL.